# How can I make the functions I wrote and debugged read only in a py file

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm a Python coder with ADHD (in my case, lacking the ability to produce enough dopamine to sustain my focus on things I do). Writing code in Python is the forest where I can produce the s**t out of it. So I enjoy writing code.

Despite my passion, I think I am still partly inefficient, about which I am sure there is a Visual Studio Code feature or extention addressing it.

**My Problem**

As I progress writing hundred of lines of code in the company of debugging, I can't prevent myself from excessively re-edit my previous code. As I go back and forth the lines, and inbetween py files, I am constantly distracted by the previous code I wrote, to which I am over stimulant to edit.Constantly changing spots of the code which is already debugged and working, I disturbingly and frequently break my projects.

**What I am looking for in VSCode** *(or if there is another IDE suggestion where I can work on multiple py files with a good layout*

Is it possible to lock some functions I finished; in other words, make the code partially read-only so that I would't unnecessarily make amendments to my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Working with git (e.g. GitHub) or some other version control system should encourage you to be more disciplined with your code edits.

Comment: I agree with @101. Additionally, if you find yourself doing this make a habit of stashing/branching and adding WIP commits so you can always look back at previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use git**

Git makes it harder to make more edits to your code, therefore making it harder to make edits. You can start off by opening a folder with VSCode. If you do not have git you can install git with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install git`. Then type `git init`.  This will initiate git in your folder. You will see a green U next to your files. Then type `git add .` this will add your changes. Then type `git commit -m "*Enter message*"` this will stage your changes. Then finally type `git push` to add it to your repository.

For more information watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkdAHXoRtos) video.

Comment: `Git makes it harder to make more edits` ??? Git does not impose anything on the edits I make, all files are fully editable